# Android Navigation Drawer menu item like Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to create an item in my Navigation Drawer that works like Facebook item "See All", when it is clicked it's open another list.
Anyone knows or have a suggestion to how to do it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: check this example https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Comment: this example also don't do what I'm looking for.
I wanna click on a menu item, called for example, "See all" and open another list in the same Navigation Drawer.

Comment: its not big deal you can use expandable list view or change listview array after click on see all, do notifydatastatechange(); or you can show new fragment inside current fragment with back button.

Answer (score 0):

change list of Menu adapter and call dataSetChanged